# Greater control of period on ui.DateSlider in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using ui.DateSlider() on Google Earth Engine. 
The `period` argument for that object seems to be the number of days (ref: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs).

I would like to control the `period` to be monthly, or semi-monthly (say 1st-14th, and 15th-end-of-month). Are these two configurations possible?

I am unable to achieve it with the `period` being restricted to number of days as the months have different days.

Sample code:

```
// Use a DateSlider to create annual composites of this collection.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1');
// Use the start of the collection and now to bound the slider.
var start = ee.Image(collection.first()).date().get('year').format();
var now = Date.now();
var end = ee.Date(now).format();

// Run this function on a change of the dateSlider.
var showMosaic = function(range) {
  var mosaic = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
    collection: collection.filterDate(range.start(), range.end())
  });
  // Asynchronously compute the name of the composite.  Display it.
  range.start().get('year').evaluate(function(name) {
    var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 100};
    var layer = ui.Map.Layer(mosaic, visParams, name + ' composite');
    Map.layers().set(0, layer);
  });
};

// Asynchronously compute the date range and show the slider.
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, end).evaluate(function(range) {
  var dateSlider = ui.DateSlider({
    start: range['dates'][0],
    end: range['dates'][1],
    value: null,
    period: 365, //<= I would like to change this to monthly or semi-monthly
    onChange: showMosaic
  });
  Map.add(dateSlider.setValue(now));
});
```

How do I change the `period` to be monthly or semi-monthly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just pass the `period: 15` for semi-monthly in the `DateSlider` constructor.

```
var dateSlider = ui.DateSlider({
    start: range['dates'][0],
    end: range['dates'][1],
    value: null,
    period: 15, // semi-monthly
    onChange: showMosaic
  });
```

This way, when an user clicks on a date, the range passed to `showMosaic` will be `[clikedDate, clickedDate+15)`. Note that in most computations with date ranges the end of the interval is open, so the last day is not included.

<s>What you cannot easily do is to restrict the date to start either on the 1st or on the 15th.</s>

The period seems to start somewhat randomly. I have just tried with a date range between `2016-Mar-01` -> `2020-Mar-31`. If you *Jump to date* 1/Mar/2016, then the period is the first half of March. Each consecutive square is the following half-month. But since some months have 31 days, it deviates from 1st->15th structure.

Comment: `period: 15` is not a solution since every month does have not 30 days. I am accepting your answer since you mentioned that it is not possible to have the slider jump to 1st and 15th of every month.

Comment: @kkrao Thanks. See my edit, please :)